# MoveIt! Euler angles or rotation vector?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, moveit-commander

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to figure out whether the MoveIt MoveGroupInterface, in particular, moveit_commander uses rotation vectors or Euler angles as orientation input. The documentation for move_group.set_position_target is not clear in this regard:

> [x, y, z, rot_x, rot_y, rot_z] or a list of 7 floats [x, y, z, qx, qy, qz, qw]

The list is then passed to [MoveGroupInterface](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/6bf3d04488a42e4e8e7153c2349c2d35103e7e50/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L1843) where it is converted by [Eigen](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/eigen_conversions/html/eigen__msg_8cpp_source.html) to a Pose (XYZ and Quaternion) which looks more like the original input should be a rotation vector.

The MoveGroupInterface also has a [setRPYTarget](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/6bf3d04488a42e4e8e7153c2349c2d35103e7e50/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L1945) function, which expects roll pitch yaw == (fixed XYZ?) Euler angles.

Therefore, I'm not 100% sure if set_pose_target expects Euler angles or a rotation vector.

Can anyone please clarify me on which pose representation is expected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291973/moveit!-euler-angles-or-rotation-vector?/) by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-23**:\

> moveit_commander uses rotation vectors or Euler angles as orientation input

I believe only if you chose to pass it a `list`. Other options are:

> a Pose message, [or] a PoseStamped message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since we don't really know if `set_pose_target` expects a rotation vector we figured it might be best to convert to a Pose message "by hand":

```
    quaternion = quaternion_from_euler(self.pose.a, self.pose.b, self.pose.c, axes='sxyz')  # static/fixed frame XYZ
    target = Pose(
        position=Point(
            x=self.pose.x,
            y=self.pose.y,
            z=self.pose.z,
        ),
        orientation=Quaternion(
            x=quaternion[0],
            y=quaternion[1],
            z=quaternion[2],
            w=quaternion[3],
        )
    )
    manipulator.set_pose_target(target, end_effector_link)
    manipulator.go()
```

---

Originally posted by [machinekoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/33820/machinekoder/) with karma: 69 on 2018-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1